# EC2 Linux 2 / phpmyadmin not found in server

Tags: linux, aws

I fallow to this guide for install LAMP:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

```
To install phpMyAdmin

Install the required dependencies.

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum install php-mbstring php-xml -y
Restart Apache.

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo systemctl restart httpd
Restart php-fpm.

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
Navigate to the Apache document root at /var/www/html.

[ec2-user ~]$ cd /var/www/html
Select a source package for the latest phpMyAdmin release from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads. To download the file directly to your instance, copy the link and paste it into a wget command, as in this example:

[ec2-user html]$ wget https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.tar.gz
Create a phpMyAdmin folder and extract the package into it with the following command.

[ec2-user html]$ mkdir phpMyAdmin && tar -xvzf phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.tar.gz -C phpMyAdmin --strip-components 1
Delete the phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.tar.gz tarball.

[ec2-user html]$ rm phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.tar.gz
(Optional) If the MySQL server is not running, start it now.

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo systemctl start mariadb
In a web browser, type the URL of your phpMyAdmin installation. This URL is the public DNS address (or the public IP address) of your instance followed by a forward slash and the name of your installation directory. For example:

http://my.public.dns.amazonaws.com/phpMyAdmin
```

After run I get 11.11.111.11/phpmyadmin
not found url on server

I try:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

add

```
Include /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/httpd.conf
```

or

```
 Include /phpmyadmin/httpd.conf
```

But this cause for me issue apache:

```
[ec2-user@server1 ~]$ sudo systemctl restart httpd
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[ec2-user@server1 ~]$
```

edit:

```
Jan 30 17:21:57 server1. systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 30 17:21:57 server1. systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 30 17:21:57 server1..com httpd[14286]: httpd: Syntax error on line 362 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf: No such file
Jan 30 17:21:57 server1.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 30 17:21:57 server1.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 30 17:21:57 server1.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 30 17:21:57 server1.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Jan 30 18:02:08 server1.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 30 18:02:08 server1.com systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

After remove this above code apache working. When I try  "include..." then this issue.

I have unzip phpmyadmin in:
/var/www/html/PhpMyAdmin

and extract correct. I dont know why this conf missing and how to add correct path to file.

Comment: Please edit your post to include output of `journalctl -u httpd`.

Comment: @Edward can you please check my update

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your case. You write `phpmyadmin`, `phpMyAdmin` and `PhpMyAdmin`. Make sure you get it right. The docs say to unpack under `/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin` so the URL should be something like http://x.x.x.x/phpMyAdmin. Case sensitivity matters!

Then, where did that Apache config file under /var/www/html/ from? This:

```
Include /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/httpd.conf
```

or this

```
Include /phpmyadmin/httpd.conf
```

makes no sense whatsoever. Delete that from the Apache config file, it's triggering the error you see in the journal.

Make sure to check the Apache config validity and reload Apache (and php-fpm to be on the safe side) afterwards by issuing:

```bsh
» httpd -t
Syntax OK

# if not OK - fix it!

» systemctl restart httpd
» systemctl restart php-fpm
```

The phpMyAdmin tarball does not contain Apache configuration directives.

Verify if http://x.x.x.x/ works (you should see the standard Apache test page) and you should see some output under http://x.x.x.x/phpMyAdmin, *if* you correctly unpacked the tarball under `/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin`.